# Get pixels/points marked by draw.line in pygame

Tags: pygame

I want to get the pixels/points marked by pygame.draw.line() function in pygame. How can this be achieved?

Comment: so you have a surface with one line, and you want to find the 2 points that the line connects?

Comment: 'all' the points marked by the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a surface, and draw the line on the surface.
Then you can loop through the surface to find the pixels that are the same color as the line.

EDIT:
you could also write a function returning the points of a [Bresenham's line algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Comment: yes, that would be one approach. But, wouldn't that be very inefficient?

Comment: I doubt you'll get a better answer. You get all the points in a surface (name it matrix). Probably later you want to ask if a certain point is part of the line and you will be able to achieve it in O(1), that's efficient!